# flutter: Refresh Indicator refreshing another state class..why?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have 3 **tabView** in my app I want a refresh indicator widget on the first 2 tabs

-> Both the first & second tab has their own Scaffold

-> Both have their own data to be refreshed on Refresh Indicator

-> Both tabs onRefresh method does the API work -> calls API & set data

But when I call refresh on the first Tab, it refreshes the second tab...why?
and since it refreshes the second tab I receive an error, because **setState** is called in the second tab onRefersh method

PROBLEM:-> Both tabs refresh should work individually

**FIRST TAB CODE**

[image]

**SECOND TAB CODE**

[image]

**OUTPUT I AM GETTING**

[**CANVA VIDEO OF THE OUTPUT**](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFH2oPPmJc/suydMvFxUn88NN64adiXPQ/watch?utm_content=DAFH2oPPmJc&utm_campaign=share_your_design&utm_medium=link&utm_source=shareyourdesignpanel)

As you can see, the refresh Indicator is not working on 1st tab though it has its own Scaffold & Refresh Indicator with its own method

Still trying to call refresh Refreshes the 2ndTab and throws an error

[image]

**THE ERROR JUST MEANS 2ND TAB REFRESH WAS CALLED, BUT HOW IS THAT POSSIBLE WHEN I AM CALLING REFRESHING THE 1ST TAB**

Comment: Can you please add some extra code? This is very ambiguous right now

Answer (score 0):

Assign keys to the scaffold. Create 2 different keys and assign one to page 1 and one to page 2.  That way flutter will get a reference on which scaffold to refresh

```dart
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey
)
```